# Implementing gravity to projectile - delta time issue

Tags: android, projectile

I'm trying to implement a simple projectile motion in Android (with openGL).
And I want to add gravity to my world to simulate a ball's dropping realistically.

I simply update my renderer with a delta time which is calculated by:

```
    float deltaTime = (System.nanoTime()-startTime) / 1000000000.0f;
    startTime = System.nanoTime();

    screen.update(deltaTime);
```

In my `screen.update(deltaTime)` method:

```
    if (isballMoving) {
        golfBall.updateLocationAndVelocity(deltaTime);
    }
```

And in `golfBall.updateLocationAndVelocity(deltaTime)` method:

```
public final static double G = -9.81;

double vz0 = getVZ0(); // Gets initial velocity(z)
double z0 = getZ0();  // Gets initial height
double time = getS();  // gets total time from act begin
double vz = vz0 + G * deltaTime;  // calculate new velocity(z)
double z = z0 - vz0 * deltaTime- 0.5 * G * deltaTime* deltaTime; // calculate new position

time = time + deltaTime; //  Update time
setS(time); //set new total time
```

Now here is the problem;

- If I set `deltaTime` as `0.07` statically, then the animation runs normally. But since the `update()` method runs as faster as it can, the length and therefore the speed of the ball varies from device to device.
- If I don't touch `deltaTime` and run the program (deltaTime's are between 0.01 - 0.02 with my test devices) animation length and the speed of ball are same at different devices. But the animation is so SLOW!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the amount you change per frame? This should make your animation 5x faster:

```
double vz = vz0 + G * deltaTime * 5;  // calculate new velocity(z)
double z = z0 - vz0 * deltaTime- 0.5 * G * deltaTime* deltaTime * 5; // calculate new position
```

Comment: One correction, you have to multiply EVERY deltaTime with 5 to run the animation x5 faster. Thank you for this!